# Secondary Attributes of Intent

Tags: android, types, android-intent, mime

I want to include various secondary attributes with intent
On developer.android.com ,i got the following info about type attribute
type -- Specifies an explicit type (a MIME type) of the intent data. Normally the type is inferred from the data itself. By setting this attribute, you disable that evaluation and force an explicit type.

I am not able to understand it ,can anybody please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean intent's putExtra(...) method?

For example:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("id", 123);
 i.putExtra("name", "name abc");
 i.putExtra("address", "aaaa 123");
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: no i mean setType() method 
this method set the type of intent
then what is "type of intent"?????

Comment: What do you want to do? I don't know why you want to set two types to the data?

Comment: i dont wnat to set two types to data

Comment: i am just asking what you mean by adding type to data

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type
http://f-del.com/blog/list-of-android-mime-types-and-uris